# Backbone: calling a success with a custom sync method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, callback

I have a custom `sync` method in my `backbone.js` app. All my models call this method, but since I override `success` in this method, my success methods from the individual models are no longer being called. Here's what I mean - Below is my custom sync method:

```
app.customSync = function(method, model, options) {
    var success = options.success,
        error = options.error,
        customSuccess = function(resp, status, xhr) {
            //call original, trigger custom event
            if(con)console.log('in custom success');
            success(resp, status, xhr);
        },
        customError = function(resp, status, xhr) {
            if(con)console.log('in custom error');
            error(resp, status, xhr);
        };
    options.success = customSuccess;
    options.error = customError;
    Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
};
Backbone.Model.prototype.sync = app.customSync;
```

Here is an example me trying to call success from a model save:

```
this.model.save({
    success:function(model, response){
         if(con)console.log('this is never called');
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how I can still the custom sync with the custom success methods, and call success from my individual saves?

As a side note, I tried calling `success` `msuccess` in the `model.save`, but the `msuccess` was undefined in the custom sync.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you are looking for, but it seems to work as is http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/XwfTB/

Comment: @nikoshr I didn't put an empty object in the save as you did in jsfiddle. If you put that in an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to [Model.save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) is a hash of attributes you wish to modify, the options come second and hold the success/error callbacks.

Try

```
this.model.save({}, {
    success: function() {
        console.log('save success');
    }
});
```

And a Fiddle to see this at work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/XwfTB/